# Run PHP onClick - session_destroy

Tags: jquery, html, php

I am looking to destroy the session when a user clicks "Log Out", I am trying to do this by calling a function onClick using jQuery which will then call a .PHP file which contains, `session_destroy();`.

index.php

```
<?php  
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
  echo "<li><a href='#' id='logOut' onclick='logOut();'>Log Out</a></li>";
}
?>
```

This makes the log out button visible only when a user is logged in and when onClick should call `logOut()` which is contained in Nav.js.

Nav.js

```
function logOut() {
  $.get("../Controller/logOut.php");
  return false;
}
```

logOut.php

```
<?php
  session_destroy();
?>
```

When I click "Log Out" nothing seems to happen and I am not getting any errors in Chrome Dev console. What is the problem?

Comment: destroying the session with ajax does'nt make the page magically reload ?

Comment: have you looked at the network tab under the developer tools to see that the $.get call is actually firing?

Comment: If you refresh the page do you still have a session?

Comment: You are not returning anything in `logout.php` so you will get nothing returned though the session may being destroyed. try echo'ing out a response in logout.php. Typically you would then need to do something with the ajax response to update your page.

Comment: Logging out through Ajax is one of the stupidest things I've ever heard of.

Comment: @Sann - it's not, but you have to update the HTML with JS as well to reflect the changes, doing an ajax request does nothing to the page that is already loaded in the browser.

Comment: @Sann - Regardless of whether or not it's the best way to go you should NEVER say "...one of the stupidest things I've ever heard of" to someone asking for help.

Comment: @AaronHathaway Yes the session is still there.

Comment: @adeneo You are right, but if the content has to reloaded then why log out user through a whole new page and redirect the use back to the home page. It is better than having to update parts of page through javascript.

Comment: Did you unset the session ID and delete the cookie (if used) as well.

Comment: One of the first lines in the [**DOCS**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php) is : "In order to kill the session altogether, like to log the user out, the session id must also be unset. If a cookie is used to propagate the session id (default behavior), then the session cookie must be deleted. setcookie() may be used for that."

Comment: There has been no cookie set to hold log in information, just the session holds this.

Comment: You do realize that `$_SESSION`'s default behavior is to store the information in a session cookie ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must have to start session before calling `session_destroy()`

```
<?php
  session_start();
  session_destroy();
  header("Location: login.php");   //redirect your page to login page
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using an AJAX request. To log out directly, just call the `logOut.php` file directly.

```
function logOut() {
  window.location = "../Controller/logOut.php";
  return false;
}
```

Or the simplest way:

```
<?php  
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
  echo "<li><a href='../Controller/logOut.php' id='logOut'>Log Out</a></li>";
}
?>
```

You might need to add a redirect to the `logOut.php` file after destroying the session.

Comment: I'm guessing that he doesn't want to reload the page at all so window.location might not be the way to go.